# Getting warning dependencies dependency while running mvn install clean command

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.coexi.appi:appi-core:jar:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 190, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.coexi.appi:appi-gc:jar:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 197, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.coexi.appi:appi-eshop:jar:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 36, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.coexi.appi:appi-front-jsf:jar:0.0.4-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 59, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-context:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.version} @ line 69, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-context:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.version} @ line 81, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-web:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.version} @ line 87, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-web:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.version} @ line 99, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-tx:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.version} @ line 105, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-tx:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.version} @ line 113, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.security.version} @ line 162, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.security.version} @ line 174, column 15
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.security.version} @ line 180, column 15
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 500, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

Comment: Please include your pom file

Comment: Here is my POM file..

Comment: You should edit your question, not post your pom in an answer

Comment: you have duplicate dependencies in your pom

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the properties spring.version and spring.security.version are set more than once.

> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.version} @ line 69, column 15

EDIT after viewing your pom file:
Your pom contains double dependency declarations.

Answer (score 0):

> 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 190, column 12

^ This warning tells you to specify version for maven-compiler-plugin located under build.plugins.plugin. Find this plugin definition on line 190 in your pom.xml and specify some version, such as `<version>3.5.1</version>`. For multi-module projects it's enough to do this in parent module if you move this plugin definition to `build.pluginManagement.plugins` section.

> 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.springframework:spring-context:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${spring.version} @ line 69, column 15

^ This warning tells you you have multiple dependencies with the same groupId and artifactId (and type and classifier, but those two are default in this case). Specifically the `groupId:artifactId:type` are `org.springframework:spring-context:jar`. Requiring the same dependency multiple times doesn't make sense and has no effect. Fix this by deleting the duplicate dependency on line 69.